# Duplicity/Deja-dup - full backup frequency

Tags: backup, deja-dup, duplicity

I setup Ubuntu backup functionality to backup my home directory. It takes full backup in a month period. Is there a possibility to change frequency of full backups? I want to setup duplicity to create only seven incremental backup and next it will be full backup. Where I can change it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yeay! I found it! :D First install dconf-editor:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
```

Second run `dconf-editor`. In path `/org/gnome/deja-dup/` is a key `full-backup-period`. Default is 90 days - every 90 days full backup is running. Changing that value is changing full backup frequency.

Answer (score 3):

As the [usage](http://duplicity.nongnu.org/duplicity.1.html) page suggests, if you run:

> duplicity /some/dir sftp://uid@other.host/some_dir

repeatedly, first it will be a full backup then all subsequent runs will be incremental. You can force it to do full backup after a particular time using the `--full-if-older-than <time>` parameter. So,

> duplicity --full-if-older-than 1M /some/dir sftp://uid@other.host/some_dir

will do a full backup every month. So you can set the first command to run for seven times and then do a full using the second command.

Comment: I ask for setup duplicity service in Ubuntu that is runned everyday, not for command options .  I setup backup of my home in Ubuntu settings but it takes full backup once per month (or something). I want to shorten that period to one week.

Comment: How did you set it up in the first place? Are you already running a cron job?

Comment: Like I'm say before, I'm using Ubuntu settings to setup backup.
http://image.qkiz.pl/di/6120/Kopie_zapasowe_006.png

Answer (score -2):

check the manpage
 http://duplicity.nongnu.org/duplicity.1.html

parameter `--full-if-older-than`